# Systematically fixing known errors in a data set

Tags: java, dataset

My essential problem is that I have read only access to a large data set.
This data set has about 300,000 records.  Some of these records
contain errors ranging from typos to chunks of missing data. Unfortunately, 
it is not possible to fix at the source and also not possible to create a 
fixed local clone.  As these errors are discovered they are relatively easy
to fix and can usually be accomplished in a few lines of code.  The problem 
I am struggling with is a sane and extensible system to allow these errors to be 
documented and fixed.

Having a method with a bunch of `if(primaryKey == 245664) {fix here}` works but
is a terrible solution.

I am writing in Java and have looked at the ServiceLoader mechanism but these feels
a bit heavyweight for my purposes.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Depending on your level and method of access... consider writing some sort of validator methods for a JPA mapped entity, called from a `@PostLoad` method.

Comment: I looked into this solution.  The issue is that each "fix" is unique. So any PostLoad method still has to determine which original record I am fixing.  And as I said before I really don't want one big method with a bunch of if statements.

Comment: You could probably store some sort of `DataFix` entity in a `HashMap`, keyed to the PK (note: if your problem is really unique to this level... you're just flat-out screwed - fix your data).  You could try to provide some sort of configurable fixes that way...  But really, you should get some sort of fixed set (local or from original).  Allowing database errors to persist is begging for trouble...

Comment: Well I figured that I was screwed but it is nice to hear it from someone else.  The data is indeed broken to the point that I need to register a custom fix for each primary key that needs it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your pain.

It may not be exactly what you want, but I suggest you take a look at Google Refine. I prefer tutorials to screencasts, but these are quite good:

http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/Screencasts

It's a real super-tool for processing data and might save you a lot of programming work. 
I am not sure if it helps automatize the process of fixing or cleaning data, but my best guess is they thought of something like that.

Comment: I am digging through this.  Not sure if it is the answer or not but either way its a very cool tool I did not know of before.